# Instant CSS Style switcher / wheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styleswitching

I am searching for a color wheel which allows to change css colours such as backgrounds etc. Where can i found a script like that? Some of you are using it.

Most of them are used on the left site in a control panel. Does somebody know where I can find a good script for it?

I really need it.

Answer (score 3):

Attach events to javascript functions, and use jQuery to change the css as desired, eg;

```
<a href="#" onclick="make_red(); return false;">Make the background red!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function make_red() {
        $('body').css("background","red");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And if you're wanting to scroll through a bunch of different colours, please for the love of god don't copy and paste that function for each one... parametrise it.